# Read the whole line till Carriage Return not Line Feed in C#

Tags: c#, readline, carriage-return, linefeed

Is it possible that I can read the whole line of a text file to the next Carriage Return rather than the Line Feed?  Currently, I'm reading lines but it counts a Line Feed (LF) as a new line but I need it to only read a new line when it hits a Carriage Return (CR).  Is it possible to store a whole line with all the Line Feeds?

```
                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                StreamWriter newFile = new StreamWriter(destination + "\\" + fileName + "_" + fileNumber.ToString() + fileExtension);
                newFile.WriteLine(header);
                newFile.WriteLine(line);

                int counter = 1;
                while (counter < fileLength)
                {
                    line = file.ReadLine();

                    if (line == null)
                        break;

                    newFile.WriteLine(line);
                    counter++;

                }
                newFile.Close();
                log.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + fileName + "_" + fileNumber.ToString() + fileExtension + " created. Card count: " + counter);
                fileNumber++;
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it counts line feeds as a new line; that's exactly what a **line feed** indicates. The combination of a carriage return and line feed makes a new line on Windows; they're a pair. Treat them as such - read a line until you reach a CR/LF **pair**.

Comment: Is it possible to NOT count line feed as a new line when reading lines and count it till it gets to that CR/LF pair ONLY?

Comment: No. A line starts with the first character and continues to the **end** of the CR/LF pair. What **exactly** is the problem you're trying to solve (other than not understanding what a line is)? I think the problem is something other than what you think it is, and you're trying to solve it based on that wrong impression. Perhaps if you explain the **real problem** you have, we can offer a suggestion how to fix it instead of trying to hack your way around it.

Comment: Do you have a text file that mixes LFs and CR/LFs?

Comment: I'm having the issue that it's going to the next line when it hits the LF.  Maybe I shouldn't be using ReadLine, I just don't know any other way to read a line till the next CR/LF pair ONLY.  Sorry if I'm not explaining it correctly.  I'm trying lol.

Comment: @SteveWellens yes I do.  Am I allowed to post that in here?

Comment: @SaifAhsanullah - I think you will have to read the file character by character and do the filtering yourself.   It's not as bad as it sounds, the OS will be buffering the data.   Or, if the file is not too large, you could read it in all at once and process it in memory.

Comment: @SteveWellens I believe you're right.  Rather than try to use the readline() method, I'll just use the read() method till it hits a cr/lf pair and then write that string and then repeat.   You think that would work ok?

Comment: @SaifAhsanullah  _You think that would work ok?_  Maybe.  We'll know when you try it.